# Cannot create a database connection SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

I will try to explain the current situation in the best possible way.

Well, I got a VM with SQL Developer already installed but could not run properly. After some reasearch, I solve the problem related with environment variables.

Currently, I need to create a database connection but unsuccessfully. I do not know what are the credentials that I have to use it. I can log in on sqlplus as sysdba.

I already did the `select * from all_users` but I am still stuck on this. Is there anyway to discover the right credentials to create the connection?

Thanks anyway.

Comment: What version of Oracle? You need to create a user/schema to use. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Please show how you called sqlplus and how you tried to connect with SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

I was putting the wrong service name. You can check yours on tnsnames.ora.